# create an XML file with nested node from a dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, nested

my starting dataframe :

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1100455", "1100456", "1100457", "1100458", "1100459", "1100464", "1100465"),
                  FR_50_LI = c("10110", "10160", "10604", "11220", "10110", "10110","10140"),
                  FR_60_LI =  c("1", "1", "1", "1", "0" ,"1", "1"),
                  FR_70_D =  c("0", "0", "0", "3", "4", "0", "0" ),
                  CL_100_E = c(2345.00,1114.58,501.40,0.00,0.00,2720.00,636.80),
                  CL_110_E = c(540.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  CL_120_E = c(563.76,0.00,17.35,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  CL_130_E = c(4100,2100,1740,265,0,3978,940)
)
```

Colnames should indicate if the information is nested or not, according to the similarity of the prefix, like "FR" or "CL". In that case for the first row it should look like this

```
<nbr n="1100455">
  <grp n="FR">
    <cat n="50">
      <col n="LI">
        <col_value>10110</col_value>
      </col>
    </cat>
    <cat n="60">
      <col n="LI">
        <col_value>1</col_value>
      </col>
    </cat>
    <cat n="70">
      <col n="D">
        <col_value>0</col_value>
      </col>
    </cat>
  </grp>

  <grp n="CL">
    <cat n="100">
      <col n="E">
        <col_value>2345.00</col_value>
      </col>
    </cat>
    <cat n="110">
      <col n="E">
        <col_value>540</col_value>
      </col>
    </cat>
    <cat n="120">
      <col n="E">
        <col_value>563.76</col_value>
      </col>
    </cat>
    <cat n="130">
      <col n="E">
        <col_value>4100</col_value>
      </col>
    </cat>      
  </grp>
</nbr>
```

What would be the quicker way, use the XML library or go with natural R ?

Comment: This might be an easier starting point: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df2, cols = -1, names_to = c("grp", "cat", "col"),  values_to  = "col_value", names_sep  = "_", values_transform = list(col_value = as.character))`

Comment: Thx this is very intersting, do you think i can do the same with spread, as my tidyr version is not up to date ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a combination of gather and separate once all of the columns are converted to character type.

Comment: this is exactly what i ve done and it give very good results, now i'm heading to make some group_by/agreggate to constitue the XML, thx